Why does my program, using WER to capture DMP files, catch a lot of fs:0053:00000018=?
I am developing a native C++ application and using WerRegisterRuntimeExceptionModule to register a DLL for capturing Windows Error Report (WER) dumps. In the DLL's processing, I filter the process names of my interest in the OutOfProcessExceptionEventCallback function, and then create dumps in the OutOfProcessExceptionEventDebuggerLaunchCallback without any filtering on the exceptions！
But the retrieved DMP files are very strange, with the stack trace as shown in the attached image.
call statck
Then I dd  2827ea54


then

.exr 2827eb90
ExceptionAddress: 7740cba6 (ntdll!LdrpInitializeInternal+0x000000aa)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000018
Attempt to read from address 00000018``

.cxr 2827ebe0
eax=00000002 ebx=2827f2b8 ecx=00000001 edx=774adaa8 esi=00000002 edi=77380000
eip=7740cba6 esp=2827f058 ebp=2827f288 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
ntdll!LdrpInitializeInternal+0xaa:
7740cba6 64a118000000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000018h] fs:0053:00000018=????????

kv
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
 # ChildEBP RetAddr      Args to Child              
00 2827f288 773ddd50     00000000 00000000 2827f2a4 ntdll!LdrpInitializeInternal+0xaa (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
01 2827f298 773ddcf1     00000000 2827f620 00000000 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b (FPO: [0,0,0])
02 2827f2a4 00000000     2827f2b8 77380000 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x11 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

On,My god！Why is this unusual problem occurring? What steps should I take to resolve it?
I hope the experts can provide some guidance。
